# Port 80 filtered nmap

Tags: nmap, port-80

Suddenly my server's port 80 is shown as filtered (no server changes are made). My sites are sometimes timing out or stays in waiting for a very long time (in browser).

Nmap localhost output is below,

```
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-05 13:12 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000025s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 984 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   open     ftp
22/tcp   open     ssh
25/tcp   open     smtp
53/tcp   open     domain
80/tcp   filtered http
106/tcp  open     pop3pw
110/tcp  open     pop3
143/tcp  open     imap
443/tcp  open     https
465/tcp  open     smtps
587/tcp  open     submission
783/tcp  open     spamassassin
993/tcp  open     imaps
995/tcp  open     pop3s
3306/tcp open     mysql
8443/tcp open     https-alt
```

Here is my iptables,

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [766174:119529463]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [425616:321228136]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [64110:3791395]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2368:111132]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2324:120618]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [423439:69482399]
:INPUT ACCEPT [423439:69482399]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [225758:163995526]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [225720:163982022]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:VZ_FORWARD - [0:0]
:VZ_INPUT - [0:0]
:VZ_OUTPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11444 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8447 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 106 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9008 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9080 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8/0 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j DROP 
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A FORWARD -i lo -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset 
-A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 32768:65535 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 32768:65535 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8880 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8443 -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT 
-A VZ_OUTPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Aug  5 13:13:10 2015
```

Tried Server restart and apache restart, no change. Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried temporarily disabling the firewall to see if this has any effect? If it does not then the issue may be at ISP Level (There firewall)

Comment: See this to learn what filtered is: http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html

Comment: What is the status of the apache service? `service apache status` or `service httpd status` _should_ provide some output. Also, what happens if you run `curl -v localhost` on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `nmap` on localhost, your firewall behaves differently than when you `nmap` from an external machine. When you do `nmap` on localhost, your packets and replies basically make it through your `INPUT`, `OUTPUT` chain twice and the exceptions for `-i lo` apply. Can you try to `nmap` from an external machine?

I cannot see that the firewall behaves differently for, say, port 22 and port 80. You could try to group all your accept rules into one large `multiport` match statement to be sure that the error is not your firewall config.

By the way: your `VZ_INPUT`, `VZ_OUTPUT` chains are never used; I suggest to delete them to clean up your ruleset.

Answer (score -1):

So in your case, the filtered state might be because some packet filtering software might be blocking/preventing the detection. This could be a firewall, router, ip rules, etc.. You could start disabling each one, one at a time to quickly see which one is the one causing the problem

try also :

```
nmap -sS -p 80 [VMIP]

-sS : Syn scan

-p 80 : port 80
```